# Why Blazor with Radzen doesn't have the same behavior in podman container?

Tags: docker, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, podman, radzen

I've been working with Blazor Server Side for a while without any problem, using Radzen Blazor nuget for the UI. The problem came when I realize that Blazor doesn't have the same behavior with some Radzen components when is deployed in a podman container.

The TreeView component doesn't work properly in the pdoman container, but locally it works fine, even in Release mode and using the same database.

In short, the problem is that the TreeView has a property that lets you to enable checkboxes in each item, but in the first component render all those checkboxes are checked, even when some of them aren't. (This only happens in the podman container).

Unlike as I mentioned above, locally it works fine, checked and unchecked checkboxes are marked as they should be. I'm not able to reproduce that bug locally, and my mind is about to explode.

I did some tests and I realize that the same image used with a docker container have the right beahvior.

- My Machine (Windows) => App Image => Docker Container => Works fine!
- My Machine (Windows) => Same Code => Debug Release => Works fine!
- Development Environment (Linux) => App Image => Podman Container => Buggg!

Additionally, I have to say that the image is made using docker and later is passed to the development environment (it's a remote server with linux) to be run with podman.

I'm using .NET6 and all nuget packages are up to date.

This is the dockerfile:

```
#Build Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal as build
WORKDIR /source
COPY . .
RUN chmod -R 777 /source
RUN dotnet restore "./Website/Website.csproj"
RUN dotnet publish "./Website/Website.csproj" -c release -o /bpms --no-restore

#Server Stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /bpms ./
EXPOSE 4000/tcp
RUN sed -i -e '1s/^/openssl_conf = default_conf\n/' -e '$a[default_conf]\nssl_conf = ssl_sect\n\n[ssl_sect]\nsystem_default = ssl_default_sect\n\n[ssl_default_sect]\nMinProtocol = TLSv1.2\nCipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -yq tzdata
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires /etc/localtime
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
ENV TZ="America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Website.dll"]
```

Comment: In browser dev tools, network tab, are there any JavaScript (or other) resources with error 404 ?

Comment: @GaëlJames There's no error, all resources load successfully :(

Comment: Time to break out the logging. Either something isn't the same with the code in the container, or the configuration of that container, or it's a networking problem. It sounds like the container itself must be the same (but do check) so I'd suspect the other two but there's no way to tell without tracking down exactly how these checkboxes get populated.